# Поцелуй может быть между кем-то и кем-то?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

> И даже невинного поцелуя между ними не было.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не может, наверное, но бывает настолько часто, что теперь уже и слух не режет.

[Здесь](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=wQ4uAAAAIAAJ&q=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B9%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83%22&dq=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B9%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiC18TFwMzhAhXTsHEKHdNkBOcQ6AEIVjAJ) аргумент в пользу "не может":

> ...Поцелуй Пети и Маши, но не *поцелуй между Петей и Машей (в книге
>   "Проблемы структурной лингвистики", 1979 г.)

Фактических примеров, когда "может" просто не счесть. Вот, например, перевод высказывания Золя, кочующий из одного солидного издания в другое:

> Золя имел все основания сказать: "Нынешний братский поцелуй между
>   Россией и Францией был подготовлен годами взаимной литературной
>   симпатии."

Comment: Гриззлинька! Скока многа я всиво нашла! *Истинный поцелуй должен выражать определенную страсть; поэтому поцелуй между братом и сестрой... / ...допускался обмен поцелуями между аналитиком и пациентом; «Удар иль поцелуй произойдет меж нами?» – «Удар, сто тысяч раз удар!»* В общем, спасибо тебе: к автору можно не приставать.

Comment: А в "корпусе" 1 раз встречается на 23 миллиона документов, причем у _журналиста_ в рецензии французского фильма (2002). Француз же Золя мог просто угодить в лапы _переводчиков_.

Comment: @Alex_ander "Вестфален считал унизительным поцелуи между мужчинами" (Галина Серебрякова — учитывая специфику её творчества, можно не сомневаться в качестве корректуры). Кстати, профессиональные переводчики зачастую грамотнее авторов, я считаю. Цитат можно найти очень много, я просто не хочу приводить их в большом количестве, отдавая предпочтение авторитетности авторов / изданий.